# regex for string to get customerID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for the word customerID number in a string. Customer id would be in this format `customerID{id}`
 so look at some different strings I would have

```
 myVar = "id: 1928763783.Customer Email: test@test.com.Customer Name:John Smith.CustomerID #123456.";
 myVar = "id: 192783.Customer Email: test1@test.com.Customer Name:Rose Vil.CustomerID #193474.";
 myVar = "id: 84374398.Customer Email: test2@test.com.Customer Name:James Yuem.";
```

Ideally I wanna be able to check if a CustomerID exists or not. If it does exists then I want to see what it is. I know we can use regext but not sure howd that look
 thanks

Comment: If you're not sure how to use a regex, the first step would be to learn some basics.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var match = myVar.match(/CustomerID #(\d+)/);
if (match) id = match[1];
```

Comment: it works for the cases you provided. do you have other cases?

Comment: @Autolycus, This works for the 3 samples you've provided. It's likely you need additional case coverage such as case-insensitivity (_customerID{id}_), number of spaces, etc... You should educate yourself on regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% farmiliar with the syntax but I'd say: "(CustomerID #([0-9]+).)"

I think this is a valid regular expression for what you're looking for, it would check if a string had 'CustomerID' followed by a space, a numer sign and then a sequence of numbers. By surrouding the numbers with brackets, they can be captured by refrencing bracket 2 if it found something

I'm not sure if the brackets or period need a \ before them in this syntax or not. Sorry I can't be of more help but I hope this helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Play around to get this to work for your needs:

```
// case-insensitive regular expression (i indicates case-insensitive match)
// that looks for one of more spaces after customerid (if you want zero or more spaces, change + to *)
// optional # character (remove ? if you don't want optional)
// one or more digits thereafter, (you can specify how long of an id to expect with by replacing + with {length} or {min, max})
var regex = /CustomerID\s+#?(\d+)/i;
var myVar1 = "id: 1928763783.Customer Email: test@test.com.Customer Name:John Smith.CustomerID #123456.";
var match = myVar1.match(regex);
if(match) { // if no match, this will be null
    console.log(match[1]); // match[0] is the full string, you want the second item in the array for your first group
}
```